# .htaccess 301 redirect to new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect some of my old sites to my new sites.  Some Googling suggest pasting this into my .htaccess:

```
redirect 301 / http://new.com/
```

However, the new site does not have the same structure as the old sites, so it's just pointing to a bunch of 404s.  How can I configure my old sites to redirect to the root of my new site, regardless of path?  eg:

```
old.com/foo -> new.com
old.com/bar/foo.html -> new.com
old.com -> new.com
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://new.com`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! :)